# Collision callback problems (chipmunk + spaceManager)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I am trying to give the bottom wall that is created with
addWindowContainmentWithFriction
a collision callback, I don't know if I am doing it wrong. This is how I have been trying to do it.

```
smgr.bottomWall->collision_type = kFootballCollisionType;
```

Am I doing something wrong because it is not responding to it. kFootballCollisionType is a collision type that I am using in other places in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting up a collision handler, using cpSpaceAddCollisionHandler? You'll need to, to get any callbacks.

```
cpSpaceAddCollisionHandler(space, kFootballCollisionType, ...
```